# Display a message to all Squid Proxy users

Tags: centos, squid

I have a production squid proxy that I am about to decommission soon. The proxy has about 400 users mainly at remote location. We have purchased a new proxy appliance and it is ready for use.

At this point of time, I can customize an error page with details on how to configure proxy settings and then disable access to all site so that these users can see this error page. But I prefer not to as the users would probably get confused and helpdesk will be flooded with calls.

I am thinking of displaying a reminder to the proxy users on the cut off date and instructions on how to configure proxy setting on their PC and they would need to click on a button to resume browsing.

Is there anyway I can achieve this with Squid Proxy? The proxy operates on a CentOS with Apache installed.

Comment: Proxy auto configuration ? Are the clients managed and can they have the proxy info pushed to them ?

Answer (score 1):

Squid supports [custom error pages](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CustomErrors), take advantage of this.

In a directory (just use the default one, `/usr/share/squid/errors` on my system), create your info page without any extension (for example `/usr/share/squid/errors/MY_CUSTOM_INFO_PAGE`), then in Squid's config create an ACL that will match all the requests you want to redirect to the info page, deny access for that ACL and use the [`deny_info`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/deny_info/) directive to serve that custom page :

```
deny_info MY_CUSTOM_INFO_PAGE myacl
```

You can also specify an URL to which the users will be redirected, just make sure that URL does not trigger the deny ACL, otherwise you'll create a redirect loop that can potentially DoS your server :

```
deny_info http://some/online/error/page myacl
```

Note that when using a custom error page (not an URL) you'll need to set the `error_directory` directive as well, unless you're ready to translate your error page in each one of the languages stored in the error page directory :

```
error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors
```

Comment: My reading of `errorpage.cc` (in Squid 3.5.20) is that you can actually put your custom error pages into the `templates/` subdirectory and not set `error_directory` and still get i18n on the non-modified pages. But you certainly can't tell from the docs.